# What type of terminal block is this?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, lamp, cables

It doesn't seem to have screws nor a button. I need to rewire the cables because of them started to split. Any ideas how to get it out?

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Do they attach further up inside that box? It looks like a regular push-style connector

Comment: Inside the box you mean the white terminal block? It's a plug system. I will add more photots

Comment: Where in the world are you?  What is this wiring part of?  A light fixture?  An appliance?   The pictographs on the last photo seem to indicate you are in a 12v light fixture of some sort.   Inside such a device, any sort of applicable wiring devices (potentially custom) may be utilized by the manufacturer.  (vs. standard mains wiring which are constrained by local codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a terminal block. That's a factory built connector, where the 2 small wires have been crimped onto the contact blade, then inserted into the connector void where it "snaps in".

Sometimes with a jeweler's screwdriver you can reach in and release the tang that holds the contact blade in the connector, but you're just as likely to break it. You will not be able to release those wires.

If this were North America, I would say, worst case, replace that connector with a ballast disconnect socket, which are readily available.